# convert Table vertical Header

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Numbers</th>
            <th>Alphabet</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>a</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>b</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Normally, the first column will show `Number 1 2`(top to bottom) and the second column is `Alphabet a b`

Now, I'd like to convert `<thead>` to vertical and `<tbody> <tr>` to vertical so that `Number 1 2` will be in a horizontal line and `Alphabet a b` will be in another horizontal one.

CSS

```
thead {
    float: left;   
}

thead th {
    display: block;   
}

tbody {
    float: right;   
}
```

The `thead` turns to vertical, but `tbody tr` doesn't.

Does anyone know how to get it work?
THANKS

Comment: why you don't change table ? See my fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/nNW9J/ !

Comment: Thank you, but I have to create the table that way.  This is for web responsive.  First, it will show normally on a big screen, then it will be converted in a small screen. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why just don't change the table layout, but I guess you have your reasons.
Anyway this was not an easy one :)

Here's the CSS code

```
table{
     display:block;
     padding: 0px;
     border-collapse:collapse;
     border-spacing:0;
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: auto;
}
thead{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}
tbody{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
tbody tr {
    float:left;
}
th, td{
   display:block;
   padding: 5px;
   margin: 0px;
}
thead > tr th:nth-child(odd) { 
       display:block; 
       float:left;
}
thead > tr th:nth-child(even) { 
   display:block;
   float:left; 
}
tbody > tr td:nth-child(odd) {
   display:block;
}
tbody > tr td:nth-child(even) { 
   display:block; 
   float:right;
}
```

and here's the demo with yout HTML table structure:
http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/83kVc/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this kind of structure if your table table is not going to change dynamically.

```
  <table>
     <tr>
        <th>Numbers</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Alphabet</th>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>a</td>
     </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My friend, in this condition,  don't use `thead` and `tbody`. Do like this,

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Numbers</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Alphabet</th>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, Shivam! but I have to create the table that way.  This is for web responsive.  First, it will show normally on a big screen, then it will be converted in a small screen. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry Zey I don't have proper idea of web responsive.